# Spring MongoTemplate - Mapping aggregation result to collections (e.g. List and Map)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

`aggregate` method of `MongoTemplate` returns `AggregationResults<T>`, where `T` being the class that corresponds to mongo collection.

Sometimes, we only want the single (say property `abc`) or a couple of properties (`pqr` and `xyz`) from that collection depending on particular criteria. In these cases, we can either retrieve the whole collection into `T` class or create a new class that contains properties (`abc`) or (`pqr`, `xyz`).

Is there a way to map these single property to `List<String>` or two properties as a key-value pair in `HashMap<String, String>`?

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it using another class having the elements I wanted instead of a map. [How to aggregate in spring data mongo db a nested object and avoid a PropertyReferenceException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57910383/7747942)

Answer (score 10):

Use `BasicDBObject` (backed by `LinkedHashMap`) / `Document` (from 2.0.0 spring mongo version) along with java 8 stream methods to parse them into collection types.

Single Property (`abc`) -  List type

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project("abc"));
List<String> singleResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "collectioname", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults().stream().map(item -> item.getString("abc")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Multiple properties (`pqr, xyz`) -  Map type

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project("pqr, xyz"));
List<Map> multipleResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,"collectioname", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults().stream().map (item -> (LinkedHashMap) item).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Update ( Reading from server )

Single Property (`abc`) -  List type

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group().push("abc").as("abc"));
List<String> singleResults = (List<String>) mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "collectioname", BasicDBObject.class).getUniqueMappedResult().get("abc");
```

Multiple properties (`pqr`, `xyz`) - Map type

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group().push("pqr").as("pqr").push("xyz").as("xyz"));
Map multipleResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,"collectioname", BasicDBObject.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: What you suggest is the more styled way of iterating aggregation results (let me know if this way is more efficient than iterating using conventional for-each loop). I was looking for a solution where the actual processing happens in MongoDB server.

Comment: Okay I've updated answer based on your comment. Please feel free to critique.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Spring-data-mongodb 2.0.10** and **mongo-java-driver 3.6.4** I changed the answer above to use **Document** instead of **BasicDBObject** onto a version that worked for me :

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                         //some aggregation code
                         );


    List<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_collection", Document.class).getMappedResults();
    List<String> resultList= result.stream().map(item -> item.get("_id").toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```